# JPA ManyToMany with extra ManyToMany relation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I need to support a scenario that involves the following entities (using JPA):

1. User
2. Account
3. Role

A user can have multiple accounts and an account can be shared among multiple users, this is a standard @ManyToMany relation so far.

A user can have a different set of roles for each account, a role can be shared among multiple users.

[image]

I've followed [this practice](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/) that explains a way to map a many-to-many association with extra columns but I'm not sure I get it.

**User entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "full_name", nullable = false)
    private String fullName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<UserAccount> usersAccounts;

    public User() {
        usersAccounts= Sets.newHashSet();
    }

    public User(String email, String fullName) {
        this();
        this.email = email;
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }



    public void addAccont(Account account) {
        UserAccount userAccount = new UserAccount(this, account);
        accounts.add(userAccount);
        account.getUsers().add(userAccount);
        this.accounts.add(userAccount);
    }

    public void removeAccont(Account account) {
        for (Iterator<UserAccount> iterator = accounts.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            UserAccount userAccount = iterator.next();

            if (userAccount.getUser().equals(this) &&
                    userAccount.getAccount().equals(account)) {
                iterator.remove();
                userAccount.getAccount().getUsers().remove(userAccount);
                userAccount.setUser(null);
                userAccount.setAccount(null);
            }
        }
    }

    //Getters  Setters..

}
```

**Account entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Account implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "billing_address", nullable = false)
    private String billingAddress;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<UserAccount> usersAccounts;


    public Account() {
        usersAccounts= Sets.newHashSet();
    }

    //Getters  Setters..
}
```

**UserAccount entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_accounts")
public class UserAccount implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserAccountId id;

    @ManyToOne(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
        })
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
        })
    private Account account;

    @ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
        })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "users_accounts_roles",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "account_id"),
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
)
private Set<Role> roles;


    private UserAccount() {}

    public UserAccount(@NotNull User user, @NotNull Account account) {
        this.user = user;
        this.account = account;
        roles = Sets.newHashSet();
        this.id = new UserAccountId(user.getId(), account.getId());
    }

    //Getters  Setters..

}
```

**UserAccountId:**

```
@Embeddable
public class UserAccountId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private String accountId;

    private UserAccountId() {
    }

    public UserAccountId(
            String userId,
            String accountId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    //Getters  Setters..
}
```

I'm creating a new user and trying to save it to the DB:

```
User user = new User("some.email@mail.com", "John Doe");
userRepository.save(savedEntity);
```

I'm getting JpaSystemException:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'user_account_account_id' doesn't have a default value
```

Looking over hibernate's create table statement I see:

```
create table users
(
  id                      varchar(255) not null
    primary key,
  email                   varchar(255) not null,
  full_name               varchar(255) not null,
  user_account_account_id varchar(255) not null,
  user_account_user_id    varchar(255) not null,
  constraint UK_exxyrhm7e34pwn8dvem8wxuxu
  unique (user_account_account_id, user_account_user_id),
  constraint FKhti2663qxk7qo15f7gfnnaj7r
  foreign key (user_account_account_id, user_account_user_id) references users_accounts (account_id, user_id)
)
  engine = InnoDB;
```

I'm not clear about the `user_account_account_id` and `user_account_user_id` columns which are marked as `not null` where as far as I understand from my entities a user can be created with no account.

Why is the table gets created this way? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My feeling is that both `user_account_account_id` and `user_account_user_id` columns are leftovers from your previous attempts. You can safely delete them and everything will work fine.

On the safe side you may delete users table altogether and recreate it from scratch.

Comment: Well, we clearly see that HN thinks you have FK from User to UserAccount. And we can see that there is no such FK in your entity declarations.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this right/make sense?

Your solution will work, it's just that it sounds a very complicated model. Are you sure the many-to-many association shouldn't be between `Role` and `Account` (and not `UserAccount`) instead? In other words, will `Account` have different `Roles` depending on which `User` is using it?

Also, I spotted an issue in your suggested mapping. You probably want:

```
@JoinTable(
            name = "users_accounts_roles",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "account_id"),
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
```

(since there's no `id` column to reference in `UserAccount`; rather, there are two primary key columns)

Comment: Regarding your question "will Account have different Roles depending on which User is using it?" - Yes, User A may have a set of roles in account A' and user B may have a different set of roles in account A'. Regarding your suggestion - Fixed, Thank you for that.